# How can I get the key of database entry Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database

[image: database]

Keys is autogenerated. **How can I give the key like a -LPW2KQ_cF82Bbx-VRXl?**

Code

```
String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .push()
                        .getKey();
```

return me a new autogenerated key.

UPDATE

Code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = objSnapshot.getKey();
                    Toast.makeText(Chat.this, key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


   }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                    Log.e("Read failed", firebaseError.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

return me a **last** valid key **-LP_mib37Ba7uGNVzk3U**.

**How can I give key for each entry I click on? ?**

Comment: Can you be more precise to what you're asking? What do you exactly want to do, get the key or generate a new key?

Comment: I want to get key for each element of listview I clicked. Now I can get only last entry database key. See corrected answer after UPDATE.

Comment: Use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` instead `SimpleAdapter` In that you will find `getKey()`

Comment: I'm using custom class with custom adapter (extend FirebaseListAdapter) for this listview.

Answer (score 0):

first you create one root child then use your sub-child. like this :

#### Users
         -LP_mib37Ba7uGNVzk3U
         -LP_mib37Ba7uGNVzk3U

try this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = objSnapshot.getKey();
                    Toast.makeText(Chat.this, key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


   }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                    Log.e("Read failed", firebaseError.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Hope it's help full for you.

Comment: I'm make it soon and reply you.

Comment: And why you think that it well be ok with sub-chlld?

Comment: Not working. All also get only the key of the last message.

Comment: With the help of debugging, I see that all keys are obtained, but because of the cycle, only the last key is returned. How to stop the cycle exactly on the position to which I click?